# ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá estou tentando fazer uma aplicação em Tkinter/python e não consigo que o código retorne o resultado do cálculo.
o código criado é o seguinte:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class Product:


    def click(self):
        l = float(self.larg.get())
        n = float(self.npeca.get())
        g = float(self.gram.get())
        print(c * l * g / n )



    def __init__(self, window):

        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('SJ Texteis, SA')
        self.wind.geometry("550x150")
        self.wind.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.wind.iconbitmap("favicon.ico")



        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='CALCULO CONSUMOS DE MALHAS')
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, pady=10, padx=25)

        Label(frame, text='Comp. do Plano: ').grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.comp = Entry(frame)
        self.comp.focus()
        self.comp.grid(row=1, column=1,)


        Label(frame, text='Largura da malha: ').grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.larg = Entry(frame)
        self.larg.grid(row=6, column=1)


        Label(frame, text= 'Nº de peças: ').grid(row=11, column=0)
        self.npeca = Entry(frame)
        self.npeca.grid(row=11, column=1)


        Label(frame, text='Gramagem: ').grid(row=16, column=0)
        self.gram = Entry(frame)
        self.gram.grid(row=16, column=1)



        ttk.Button(frame, text='Calcular Cons./peça', command=self.click).grid(row=25, column=2)

        self.cons = Entry(frame)
        self.cons.grid(row=25, column=7, padx=10, pady=5)







if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()

    application = Product(window)

    window.mainloop()
```

Onde é que estou a errar?

Comment: Poderia postar a mensagem de erro inteira na pergunta?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\juliofaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/juliofaria/PycharmProjects/consumos/index.py", line 8, in click
    l = float(self.larg.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Não mostra o valor que ele tentou converter para float no final desta mensagem?

Comment: Não mostra mais nada. O erro aparece ao clickar o botão.

Comment: E você chega a informar algum valor para a largura da malha?

Comment: ao testar com valores, aparece o seguinte erro:

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96898/discussion-between-julio-faria-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Comment: Já consegui! faltava a var. c  (   c = float(self.comp.get())